# Convert Timestamp to Datetime Format in Java Spring/Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I created a table in oracle which automatic add timestamp after add data. However, in database the format is like this:

```
12/10/2017 11:16:21.000000000
```

But after it parse from backend to HTML using AngularJS, it shows like this

```
1507778181000
```

Here come my code in bean.java:

```
    @Column(name="AUDIT_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Timestamp auditDate;
```

May I know is that any method to display that timestamp in a datetime format? Where should I implement that method? Should I implement the method in Bean/DAO, or I make it in front-end?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat

Comment: where should i implement it? in DAO or Bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing modify the code in Java backend code, I use a built in function in AngularJS called **date filter** :

```
{{ date | date : format : timezone }}
```

This is what I did to convert the date to the format that I wanted.

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp